# TestNg IReporter listener - test start and end time

Tags: listener, testng

I am using a sample listener from.  http://relevantcodes.com/testng-listener-using-extentreports/

Does someone know how to get the time test was started and end from the listener?

I checked. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/SuiteHTMLReporter.java#L424 but its not clear how time info is pulled from. The code does

```
iim.getDate()
```

But I don't understand how that provides the diff because it just subtracts diff from itself only.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can implement your own listener and get the time if that is all you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karthik

I have updated the post, you can use the new code to retrieve started and ended times:

```
test.getTest().startedTime = new Date(result.getStartMillis());
test.getTest().endedTime = new Date(result.getEndMillis());
```

In TestNG, you can retrieve starting and ending milliseconds, which can be converted to `Date`.

Comment: Thanks Anshoo. Works!